# Recuperar tildes en C#

Tags: c#, string

No consigo recuperar un texto con tilde en un `StringBuilder` de [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

El ejemplo tonto sería el siguiente:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sbEx = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sbEx.Append("<br />Hoy es día " + dia.ToShortDateString() + ".");
return sbEx.ToString();
```

Este código devuelve `"Hoy es dÃ­a 03/07/2017"`.

¿Cómo puedo recuperar la tilde?

Comment: Ese código devuelve una cadena correcta,con su tilde. El problema no debe estar ahí, sino donde muestras esta cadena.

Comment: Con un punto de parada en el return e inspeccionando sbEx.ToString() veo que el valor devuelto es "Hoy es dÃ­a 03/07/2017". Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Es asp.net? mvc?

Comment: Es asp.net y no es mvc.

Comment: Si al inspeccionar `sbEx.ToString` ya te aparece sin el carácter  correcto, lo único que se me ocurre es que tienes algun problema de codificación en tu código. El ejemplo que pones funciona perfectamente, mira [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DJX4gq) un ejemplo.

Comment: Encontré este link que te podría ayudar en tu tema. [Resolver Acentos y Ñs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/daniem/2009/12/01/acentos-y-ees-no-se-muestran-correctamente/)

Answer (score 3):

Por algun motivo te esta cogiendo mal el charset, prueba a traducir-lo

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str);
str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto es producido mayormente por falta de la codificación [`UTF-8`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_charactersets.asp) a las paginas web:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
</html>
```

En [cristalab.com puedes encontrar mas informacion.](http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/configurar-tu-web-para-usar-utf-8-c42532l/)

Answer (score 0):

En vez de cambiar esto en el HEAD|META de cada página, o en una vista compartida, lo mejor es incluirlo en el web.config. La codificación ISO-8859-1 permite reconocer los caracteres con tilde (áäâà) y eñes.

```
<globalization requestEncoding="ISO-8859-1" responseEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Como te mencionaron, el archivo que ve el texto debe tener la codificación UTF-8

ejemplo archivos html

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

pero además los archivos deben ser guardados con codificación UTF-8, si no me equivoco esto viene por defecto, pero si no lo estuviese o si lo cambiaste por error hay unas formas de arreglarlo

en visual studio te vas a

`Herramientas -> Opciones -> Entorno -> Documentos"`

`Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Documents"`

y le das a la opción

"Guardar los documentos como Unicode cuando no se puedan guardar los datos en la página de códigos"

**Otra** forma de hacerlo es en

`Archivo -> Opciones Avanzadas de guardado` y ahí te dará opciones para guardar los archivos en formato UTF-8

ahora si tienes VS2017 o superior (yo tengo vs2019), esta opción no está habilitada por defecto en este caso debes o bien habilitarla dentro de los comandos o bien darle a

`Archivo -> Guardar Como...`

una vez en la ventana para guardar como en el botón que dice "Guardar" tiene una flecha, la presionas y te da la opción de guardar con codificación y te saldrá una lista para darle la codificación al archivo.

Espero y te ayude

Answer (score 0):

Por si ha alguien le sirve.
He tenido un problema similar al intentar colocar acentos en el `<meta description>` mediante `Viewbag`. Al final lo he solucionado haciendo uso de `@html.raw`...

```
meta name="description" content="@Html.Raw(ViewBag.description)"
```

Esto permite representar el viewbag como código html y me ha funcionado.